# Android Layout is overlapping itself

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using fragments in my app. Below is the screenshot of my app. Everything looks fine on activity launch. But, when I change the screen orientation, the layout overlaps itself while scrolling. Any ideas what is wrong?

**EDIT (Solution):** 
I found out what was wrong. A new fragment was added on orientation change. I was previously using `fragmentTransaction.add(...)`, I replaced it with `replace` method.

Comment: Narrowing down the problem is pretty much impossible unless you post your layouts and the code where you are handling the fragments.

Comment: How are you calling these fragments? I had this same problem when I changed a `View`'s id inside a `Relative Layout`. Can you show your xml codes?

Answer (score 0):

For future vistor's understanding...

You are most likely adding your fragment in your activity's onCreate().

When your device is rotated, your activity is destroyed and re-created, but it also recreates any added fragments.

With these two things in mind...

1. onCreate is called and you add a fragment to your activity.  You have one fragment.
2. You rotate the screen.
3. The activity is destroyed and re-created.  Your fragment is destroyed and recreated.  You still have one fragment.
4. Your activity calls onCreate() as a part of its recreation, which adds a fragment to your activity.  You now have two fragments.

If one or both of your fragments have transparent backgrounds, both may display at once, as is likely the case here.

Either use replace instead of add (which you have done), or better, only add the fragment in onCreate() if `savedInstanceState` is null.  If it is null it means it's the first onCreate() call.